# Apply an IWrapTestMethod attribute to a whole fixture?

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-3.0

I have an NUnit `IWrapTestMethod` attribute:

```
public class OutputElapsedTimeAttribute : Attribute, IWrapTestMethod
{
    public TestCommand Wrap(TestCommand command)
    {
        return new OutputElapsedTimeCommand(command);
    }
}
```

and a corresponding BeforeAndAfterTestCommand:

```
public class OutputElapsedTimeCommand : BeforeAndAfterTestCommand
{
    private Stopwatch _sw;

    public OutputElapsedTimeCommand(TestCommand innerCommand) : base(innerCommand)
    {
        BeforeTest = ctx => { _sw = Stopwatch.StartNew(); };
        AfterTest = ctx =>
        {
            _sw.Stop();
            ctx.OutWriter.WriteLineAsync($"Took: {_sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
        };
    }
}
```

When I apply the attribute to a test method, the command is properly called and executed. I want to be able to put the attribute on the test fixture though and apply it to all tests within the test fixture automatically. How to do that? I can't find anything suitable in the docs.

Comment: Have you seen this article https://www.skyrise.tech/blog/tech/extending-nunit-3-with-command-wrappers/ where they state *`Mind, that we only allow to use attribute on methods, since I believe command wrappers don’t support decorating test fixtures.`*

Comment: Hm...is there a different way to achieve what I am trying then?

Comment: Not that I am aware of currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface is only called by NUnit on tests that have an attribute with that interface. It would be reasonable for NUnit to also call attributes on the fixture containing each test, but it doesn't do that so it would require an enhancement to NUnit itself.

As a workaround, consider creating an [Action Attribute](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Action-Attributes)

Comment: Thank you for the "definitive" answer. I'm gonna file a feature request at GitHub :-)